# PHP in AJAX with WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a function the_rooms defined as:

```
function the_rooms() {
    $latteParams['post'] = WpLatte::createPostEntity(
        $GLOBALS['wp_query']->post,
        array(
            'meta' => $GLOBALS['pageOptions'],
        )
    );
    $rooms = wp_get_post_terms($latteParams['post']->id, 'ait-dir-item-rooms');
        if ( !empty( $rooms ) && !is_wp_error( $rooms ) ){
            foreach ( $rooms as $room ) {
                echo $room->name;
            }
    }
}
```

This works in my single.php, but when I call it in another file, map-single-javascript.php:

```
data:
    '<div class="marker-holder">
        <div class="marker-content with-image">
            <a href="{!$item->link}">
                <img src="{thumbnailResize $item->thumbnailDir, w => 120, h => 160}" alt="">
                <div class="map-item-info">
                    <div class="title">
                        &#36;'+{ifset $item->optionsDir["price"]}{$item->optionsDir["price"]}+{/ifset}' 
                        <small><?php the_rooms(); ?>bd/<?php the_baths(); ?>ba</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address">
                        '+{$item->optionsDir["address"]|nl2br}+'<br>'+{$item->optionsDir["address2"]|nl2br}+'
                    </div>
                    <div class="timestamp">
                        <?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <div class="close">x</div>
        </div>
    </div>'
```

It returns nothing. However, `<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>` works and returns the correct time for each post.

I can't wrap my mind around why human_time_diff works but my the_rooms won't.

Is this because it isn't being called inside the loop? If so, neither is human_time_diff, but it works. How can I get it to work in map-single-javascript.php?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is this function `human_time_diff()`. ?

Comment: @Cucumber Are you getting any errors and/or are you viewing the php error logs that can be turned on in your php.ini file? If not sure how to do that, here is an explanation: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html

Comment: @Adeel, I just updated my post to reflect where human_time_diff() is called. It's in the second block of code in the div class "timestamp."

Comment: Perhaps you've not shown the complete code , that's why it's getting difficult to understand.

Comment: @Adeel, human_time_diff isn't my function. It's defined by WordPress in wp-includes/formatting.php.

Comment: well for 1 if the above is PHP, the php '+' is for addition, for combining statements its '.'

Comment: Here's map-single-javascript.php: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/adfedb7495f3a6340781

Comment: @David - That's not it. I changed the '+' to '.' and it didn't affect anything.

Comment: well no it wouldn't, its all js.

Comment: Try a echo $latteParams['post']->id just before its used in wp_get_post_terms() to see if you have a post id and then var_dump $rooms.

Comment: I tried that and it worked on the single.php, but not that one. I think I'm just going to outsource this.